# i can't understand this 'marge manifest' error

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I'm working on a chatting app using Firebase Database. & while working on it i'm getting this error whenever I try to run the app.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-30:19 to override.
```

Here is my manifest code

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.theroos.chatapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".VerifyActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingservice">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this error & how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried adding 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" to your manifest?

Comment: Add two lines in your gradle.properties - android.useAndroidX=true And
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: I've tried but not working.. Its can't indentify useAndroidX & enableJetifier.. @Dhanshri

Comment: look for your dependency and try remove unnecessary dependency

Comment: I've tried that but it still shows "marger manifest failed with multiple errors please see logs." @StanislavShamilov

Comment: @Roo S Add this line in your <application> tag this - tools:replace="android:allowBackup"

Answer (score 0):

-Try placing this two lines in manifest's application tag:

```
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
```